Deleted partition recovery: Contents unknown
I accidentally deleted all partitions (2) of my HDD, but I was only able to recover single partition. I have recovered the second partition as well but when I try to mount it, it does not mount. I used testdisk to recover the partitions.
My Partitions image
I used the following command to mount the partition.
> sudo mount /dev/sda2 /
mount: /: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.


As you appear to have used a Windows tool in this case TestDisk the file type is most likely one that Ubuntu does not use. Time for a fresh install of Ubuntu. A good general rule to follow, never use Windows tools on anything non Windows.

@David
I was recommended to used TestDisk by askubuntu post. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery
I also tried plugging it into windows system and using chkdsk but it says corrupted partition.
